# Collapse data with rules for a list of data frames

Tags: r, max, flatten

I have a data frame that I need to collapse based on a defined group. The data consist of several hundred groups. Each group may have anywhere from 2-5 rows. For simplicity, my example shows 3 groups with 2-4 rows.

I want to flatten the replicates within each group. For each column in a group, I want to return the maximum occurring value that is not NA. The issue lies in what to do in the case of a tie. For ties, I need to set custom rules based on the types of values that are tied. One potential desperate option would be to paste the tied values together separated by a comma and I can deal with them in find/replace fashion.

To get the maximum occurring value, I was able to use the max function. Any suggestions on how to deal with ties?

```
#Input Data Example
> data
   Group Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Loc4
1 Group1  A/B  A/A  B/B   NA
2 Group1  A/B  A/A  B/B  A/A
3 Group1  A/A  A/A  A/A   NA
4 Group1  A/A  A/A  A/A   NA
5 Group2  A/A   NA  C/C  B/B
6 Group2  B/B  A/A  C/C  B/B
7 Group2  B/B  A/A  C/C  B/B
8 Group3  B/B  B/B   NA  B/B
9 Group3  B/B  B/B   NA  A/A

#Desired Collapsed Output
> data.collapsed
   Group Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Loc4
1 Group1   NA  A/A  A/B  A/A
2 Group2  B/B  A/A  C/C  B/B
3 Group3  B/B  B/B   NA  A/B
```

FINAL Code (updated Jan 27,2015)

```
library(data.table)
#Data Frame
#Each group has replicates of data that need to be collapsed to make a consensus data replicate
data = rbind(c("Group1","A/B", "A/A","B/B",NA), c("Group1","A/B", "A/A","B/B","A/A"), c("Group1","A/A", "A/A","A/A",NA),
         c("Group1","A/A", "A/A","A/A",NA), c("Group2","A/A", NA,"C/C","B/B"), c("Group2","B/B", "A/A","C/C","B/B"), 
         c("Group2","B/B", "A/A","C/C","B/B"), c("Group3","B/B", "B/B",NA,"B/B"), c("Group3","B/B", "B/B",NA,"A/A"))
colnames(data) = c("Group", "Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3", "Loc4")
data = as.data.frame(data)
data

#Define acceptable value types; these could be used to define what to do in the case of a tie
same.letter = c("A/A","B/B","C/C")
diff.letter = c("A/B","A/C","B/C")

#Function for collapsing data with rules
RepMerge = function(col) {
  z = table(col);
  z.max = which(z==max(z));

  ifelse(length(z.max) > 2, "NA",  #if tied between more than 2 different values, report NA
      ifelse(length(z.max) == 1, names(z)[z.max], #if one max value, report that value
          ifelse(length(z.max) == 2 & names(z)[z.max][1] %in% same.letter & names(z)[z.max][2] %in% same.letter, paste(substring(names(z)[z.max][1],1,1),substring(names(z)[z.max][2],1,1), sep="/"), #if both max values are different but are in 'same.letter', report a combination
              ifelse(length(z.max) == 2 & names(z)[z.max][1] %in% diff.letter | names(z)[z.max][2] %in% diff.letter, "NA", "Check Code")))) #if one of the max values is in diff.letter, report NA. If no cases fit the above, report "Check Code"
}

setDT(data)[,lapply(.SD,RepMerge),Group] # run function to collapse the data
```

Thank you,
SC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution based on `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,lapply(.SD,function(cl) {z<-table(cl);z.max<-which(z==max(z));ifelse(length(z.max)>1,"NA",names(z)[z.max])}),Group]

#    Group Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Loc4
#1: Group1   NA  A/A   NA   NA
#2: Group2  B/B  A/A  C/C  B/B
#3: Group3  B/B  B/B   NA   NA
```

By modifying `ifelse`, you can set the desired rules for treating ties and NAs.

PS: You were curious about why the `max` function ignores NAs in your code. It happens because your data table contains strings 'NA', not actual `NA`s.

Comment: Regarding the "NA", yea I thought of that when I woke up this morning :-). I'll corrected it in my post. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try it out and let you know how it works. Thanks!